# Regex - Match a string which has zero or one spaces

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match a string which starts with @, can contain any amount of letters or numbers but can only contain a maximum of one space (or zero spaces).  So far I have

```
@([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

which matches the characters but without the space.  I think I need \s{0,1} but I'm not sure where to put it.. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: can the String be `abc[space]`? i.e, can it end with a space?

Comment: or begin with one for that matter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you only care about spaces in the word, not leading or trailing then you could use this:

```
@[A-Za-z0-9]* ?[A-Za-z0-9]*
```

Explanation:

`@`             Starts with literal @

`[A-Za-z0-9]`   Any letter or number

`*`             Letter or number can be length {0,infinity}

`?`            Space char, 0 or one times

`[A-Za-z0-9]*`  Any number of trailing letters or spaces after the space (if there is one)

Comment: Works well but only with the `matches` method. (However, I don't see a reason to use an other method in the present case)

Comment: it matches only `@` also.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Yes but the question said : "any amount of letters or numbers"

Comment: `matches` just appends `^` in front and `$` behind. I purposely left those off so that it could be used with `matches` and `find`

Comment: @AdamYost: These anchors are very important if you use the `find` method, otherwise your will obtain a result for each substring that fits the pattern.  Example, with `abc@def` the `find` method will return `@def` if you don't use anchors.

Comment: I know, but the anchors tie you to the searched string being a full line. Lets say their string is:

`s = "I am searching for id=@abc def today, I hope I find it!"`

Find will return `@abc def` while matches will return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex to match the words which starts with `@` follwed by any number of letters or numbers with an optional space,

```
^@[a-zA-Z0-9]+ ?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wY8kG1/18)

Java pattern would be,

```
"^@[a-zA-Z0-9]+ ?[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
```

Comment: @Braj failed to update the demo link. Now it seems ok.

Comment: `\s` also allows for tabs and newlines. If they really only allow spaces, this is no good, as it will accept `\t` or `\n`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex with negative lookahead:

```
^@((?!(?:\S* ){2})[A-Za-z0-9 ]+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you needed?

```
@[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\s?)[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/hY2mB2/1)